# How to get hour min and am/pm from string that contains HH:MM AM/PM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I got string like this :

```
"10:00 AM"

"11:30 AM"

"12:00 AM"
```

from this stringi I want to know HOUR and Mins and AM / or PM as separate values.

Comment: This question is very appreciated and is NOT a duplication of the other one, some users are really mean and just trying to get points and harming other users. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "10:00 AM";
var array = s.Split(new string[] {":", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[0]); //10
Console.WriteLine(array[1]); //00
Console.WriteLine(array[2]); //AM
```

Output will be;

```
10
00
AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/QAGzat)</kbd>.

Or better way, you can use [`Convert.ToDateTime(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for your string like;

```
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime("10:00 AM");
Console.WriteLine(dt.Hour);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Minute);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("tt"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output will be;

```
10
0
AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/YTeYAj)</kbd>.

**EDIT**: As andleer *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022705/how-to-get-hour-min-and-am-pm-from-string-that-contaian-hhmm-am-pm/20022746#comment29816890_20022746)*, using [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can a better option.

Comment: I think DateTime.Parse is a better option. Convert.ToDateTime will handle a null but return DateTime.MinValue. Both through an SystemFormat exception if that passed value can't be converted / parsed.

Comment: @andleer You have a point. Thanks. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse into a DateTime object like this:

```
string timeString = "10:00 AM";
DateTime timeObject = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "hh:mm tt", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Substring()` function to get the Part of the String

```
Syntax: Substring(int startIndex,int length);
```

**Sample1:**

```
String strDate = "10:00 AM";
String HH = strDate.Substring(0, 2);//10
String MM = strDate.Substring(3, 2);//00
String tt= strDate.Substring(6, 2);//AM

Console.WriteLine(HH+":"+MM+" "+tt);
```

**Output:**  10:00 AM

You can also use `ToString()` function get the required part of `Time`

**Sample2:**

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("HH"));
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("mm"));
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**Output:**

```
10  
00  
AM
```